# Can't update pip in VS code. Says { unknown command "update"}

Tags: python, pip

OS: Win10

Environment: Visual Studio code

What I want to achieve: Update pip from 22.0.4 to 22.1

What I tried and get:

1. `python -m pip install -–upgrade pip`

get:

```
python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ python -m pip install -–upgrade pip
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

2. `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`

get:

```
sudo : The term 'sudo' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or    
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip
+ ~~~~
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

3. `pip update`

get:

```
ERROR: unknown command "update"
```

4. check if python installed in this location:

> ```
> py -3 --version
> ```

get:

```
Python 3.10.4
```

5. check if pip installed in this location:

> `pip --version`

get

```
> pip 22.0.4 from
> C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip
> (python 3.10)
```

6. use "python3" instead of "python"

> `python3 -m pip install -–upgrade pip`

get:

```
> > `python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the  name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
> + python3 -m pip install -–upgrade pip
> + ~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException`
```

Problem: I can't update pip in VS code, what else should I try or check?

Comment: sudo is not exported in windows machines or in powershell, so that is expected

Comment: I would try python3 instead of pyuthon

Comment: Hi! I've tried python3 but it still gives error. I posted what I input and what I got in the question.

Comment: Use `py -3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are really close. Based on your errors this should work:

```
py -3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Or

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Make sure to run this in a administrator command prompt. Right click cmd and select "run as administrator". This will avoid permission errors.

## Why your other options don't work

1. `python -m pip install -–upgrade pip`: Doesn't work since python is installed as `py -3` not as python.
2. `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip`. Sudo is a linux only command
3. `pip update`. update is not a pip command. Why didn't you just use `install --upgrade pip` here? The error shows pip is installed and called pip so that would work.
4. `python3 -m pip install -–upgrade pip`. Python isn't called `python3` either, but `py -3`. Overall the `py -x` syntax is the most reliable way to get python on windows.

## What is `py -3`

`py -3` is a windows utility that finds python. It's pretty versatile, for example you can type `py -3.9` to get specifically the 3.9 version.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer solved the problem!

Comment: I didn't use `install --upgrade pip` there because there was another error `The term 'install' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`. I'll try to find out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a cmd/powershell if on windows or terminal if on linux. Just paste the same command and try it

Hope it helps

If it doesn't work i think that you haven't added python/pip to path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying CMD for that, if still not working, try adding your python path to the system variables. If you don't know how to do that here a tutorial for you: https://www.makeuseof.com/python-windows-path/

Comment: No need to do that, the `py` utility is already on the path and it's a much more reliable way to get python than adding a individual version to your path

Comment: got it, then the command will be: `py -3 -m pip install --update pip`